# Как сделать чтобы возвращаемые значения из одной функции можно было использовать в другой функции?

Tags: c++, функции, указатели, ссылки

Функция findMinMax возвращает min, max. Как сделать чтобы в функции production использовались значения min, max из первой функции?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void fillArray(int *A, int n)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
    {
        A[i] = rand() % 50 + 1;
    }
}

void outputArray(int *A, int n)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cout << A[i] << " ";
    }
}

int findMinMax(int *A, int n, int min, int max)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
    {
        min = A[1];
        max = A[1];
        if (A[i] > max) max = A[i];
        if (A[i] < min) min = A[i];
    }
    return min, max;
}

int production(int *A, int n, int min, int max)
{
    min = min / 2;
    max = max / 2;
    cout << "MIN: " << min << endl;
    cout << "MAX: " << max << endl;
    int P = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if ((A[i] <= max) && (A[i] >= min)) P *= A[i];
        A[1] = P;
        A[n-1] = P;
    }
    return P;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RU");
    const int n = 10;
    int A[n];
    int min = A[1];
    int max = A[1];
    fillArray(A, n);
    cout << "Исходный массив A: ";
    outputArray(A, n);
    findMinMax(A, n, min, max);
    production(A, n, min, max);
    cout << "Преобразованный массив A: ";
    outputArray(A, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Выдаёт ошибки что использованы неинициализированные локальные переменные min, max. Пробовал ставить указатели, ссылки в параметрах функции, менял тип на void и т.п. но на данный момент не могу понять в чём проблема.

Comment: Функция `findMinMax` **НЕ** возвращает `min`, `max`. И вопрос надо задать "как сделать, чтобы эта функция возвращала значения. И получить ответ — передавать их в функцию по ссылке...

Comment: @Harry ты имеешь ввиду в параметрах функций поставить & перед этими переменными?

Comment: Не только. У вас вся функция написана неверно — см. мой ответ.

Answer (score 3):

У вас функция неработающая. Потому что она не находит ни минимум, ни максимум, и возвращает только максимум между `A[1]` и `A[N-1]`.

Начнем с того, что в вашем варианте непонятно, зачем вам вообще передавать `min` и `max`, а не объявлять их локально? Вы хотите получать в переданных аргументах возвращаемые значения? Тогда передавайте их по ссылке: не

```
int findMinMax(int *A, int n, int min, int max)
```

а

```
int findMinMax(int *A, int n, int& min, int& max)
```

Но если вы возвращаете значения через аргументы — то `int` не нужен:

```
void findMinMax(int *A, int n, int& min, int& max)
```

Поехали дальше:

```
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
    {
        min = A[1];
        max = A[1];
```

Т.е. на каждой итерации вы снова и снова присваиваете значение `A[1]` и сравнения выполняете только с ним. Зачем?

Логичнее

```
        min = A[0];
        max = A[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
    {
```

Тем более что нумерация элементов массива начинается с 0. Правда, вы везде почему-то начинаете нумерацию с 1. Это имеет какой-то смысл?... Тогда замените в строках выше 0 на 1.

```
        if (A[i] > max) max = A[i];
        if (A[i] < min) min = A[i];
    }
```

Теперь

```
    return min, max;
```

не нужен, но он и раньше не работал — потому что возвращал только ([*читайте об операторе "запятая"*](http://www.c-cpp.ru/books/operator-zapyataya)) одно значение — `max`, а не, как вам казалось, два...

Comment: как тогда получить два значения min, max?

Comment: По-моему, я уже разжевал все ошибки в функции... Показал все строки, которые надо заменить, и на что именно заменить. Что вам еще неясно?

Answer (score 2):

Просто передавайте из `main` параметры по ссылке

```
int findMinMax(int *A, int n, int& min, int& max) {}
int production(int *A, int n, int& min, int& max) {}

int main()
{
    int min = A[1];
    int max = A[1];
 
    findMinMax(A, n, min, max);
    production(A, n, min, max);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А в `production`-то зачем их передавать по ссылке? 8-/

Comment: По инерции написал :) С другой стороны в `production` с этими параметрами выполняются действия - вполне возможно что новые значения `min` и `max` будут потом нужны.